# maskMoney Jquery no GridView

Tags: jquery, .net, gridview, maskmoney

Pessoal eu Preciso fazer uma mascara de moeda usando o MaskMoney onde os TextBox vem de um GridView gerado dinamicamente ou seja não sei quantas linhas tem nele.
Estou fazendo dessa forma mas ele só funciona com a primeira linha do GridView. Como que eu faço pra que ele considere todas as linhas e não somente a primeira?

```js
            <script>
                $(function () {
                    $('#ctl00_c_area_conteudo_grd_fornecedor_lance_ctl02_txtVL_Lance').maskMoney(
                        {
                            allowNegative: false,
                            thousands: '.',
                            decimal: ',',
                            affixesStay: false,
                            symbol: "R$",
                            precision: 4

                        }


                        );
                })
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah ja consegui resolver simples

var gvDrv = document.getElementById("<%= grd_fornecedor_lance.ClientID %>");
                    for (i = 1; i < gvDrv.rows.length; i++) {

```
                        $('#ctl00_c_area_conteudo_grd_fornecedor_lance_ctl0' + i.toString() +'_txtVL_Lance').maskMoney(
                            {
                                allowNegative: false,
                                thousands: '.',
                                decimal: ',',
                                affixesStay: false,
                                symbol: "R$",
                                precision: 4

                            }


                            );
```

}